# Netbeans 7.1.2 - Showing key bindings

Tags: netbeans

I just realised that the key bindings do not appear next to the different IDE functionalities.
For example it used to show Shift+ctrl+F next to the Source>Format option. I looked into settings but didnt find a way to bring that back. Anyone knows if there is a way to do it?
I am running the OSX version of netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under options (Netbeans menu -> Preferences on the mac, under tools menu for Windows IIRC), there is the keymap. I'm not 100% if all of them are there, but it's good start.

Comment: Windows: Tools > Options > Key Map